# Ferramenta para Medir Desempenho de Software Java

Tags: java, eclipse, algoritmo

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma ferramenta para medir o d`esempenho de um algoritmo`.

Vou dar um exemplo:

Tenho dois algoritmos de ordenação, e queria medir quanto `tempo`, `memória` e etc.. cada um gasta

Tenho usado o `Java Monitor do Eclipse` porém não estou confiando muito nos resultados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, tem uma maneira sim, existe uma API que eu projetei para atender isso, usando Programação Orientada a Aspectos. Não quero aqui entrar em detalhes sobre o paradigma, mas vamos atender sua necessidade.

**Primeira Opção - Green Aspect Utils**
Esse é meu framework com Aspectos, incluindo o de Log com nivel de profiling. Se quiser utilizar meu Framework, acesse este link:

https://github.com/FilipeGMiranda/Green-Aspect-Utils

Basta adicionar a anotação @LoggableObject logo asima do seu método, desta maneira:

```
@LoggableObject(logMode={LoggableObject.LogModes.PROFILE})
    private int seuMetodo(String a, Integer b, String y, Object o, String c){
        //Conputacoes e execucao de seus algoritmos
        return 1;
    }
```

Obs.: Para usar meu framework você vai precisar do minimamente do Maven

Quando você fizer a execução desse programa, você verá essas informações que você quer.

**Segunda Opção, apenas use uma ferramenta de profiling, como JConsole, JProfile**

O JConsole está na pasta C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin

**Terceira Opção - Escreva seu próprio código de profiling**

Que será algo nesse template:

```
public static void seuMethod() {
    // sua logica
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Memória total
    System.out.println("Memória total: "
            + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());

    // Memória livre
    System.out.println("Memória livre: "
            + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());

    // Tempo de inicio
    long initialTime = System.nanoTime();

    seuMethod();

    System.out.println("Tempo de execução total --> "
            + (System.nanoTime() - initialTime));

    System.out.println("Memória total: "
            + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());

    // Memória livre
    System.out.println("Memória livre: "
            + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());

}
```

Leia os comentários do código, deve te ajudar

**Note o uso dos métodos antes e depois da execução de seus métodos.**

- Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
- Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()

Comment: Grato pela Ajuda Felipe!

Comment: É pra isso que estamos aqui, me deixe saber se tudo funcionar normalmente. E me siga no GItHub, para acompanhar a evolução da API